# Jquery Mobile - Popup without style

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've read popups should be in the same page of the anchor which calls them; however how does it work with multipage pages?

The issue I'm having is that popup shows up, but the elements inside it are not styled jquerymobile style, they appear plain...

This works:

```
<body>
    <a onclick="$('#categoriesPopup').popup('open');" data-role = "button">Open</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="categoriesPopup" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>Weapons</li>
            <li>Shields</li>
            <li>Armor</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id = "title" data-title="Troria">
        <a onclick="$('#categoriesPopup').popup('open');" data-role = "button">Open</a>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="popup" id="categoriesPopup" class="ui-content">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>Weapons</li>
                    <li>Shields</li>
                    <li>Armor</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't see any difference: http://jsfiddle.net/FaFhz/ , http://jsfiddle.net/FJRbs/ Check and post the rest of the code ^^

Comment: I found the issue! I had this on <head>
<script>
$( document ).ready( function(){
 $("#categoriesPopup").popup();
} );
</script>

Seems like it didn't like the double initialisation (?)

Comment: It seems so ^^ Glad to know it

Comment: JQM and $(document).ready is an absolutely NOGO! See jqm documentation: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was invoking the popup() initialisation in the document.ready, seems like it screwed up with the double initialisation (because of the data-role "popup")

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function(){
    $("#categoriesPopup").popup();
} );
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using JQM 1.4 and the popup is external, your solution is correct. If you're using older version, it isn't correct. Popup should be placed as a child of page div.

Comment: I'm using JQM 1.3.2, seems like in the first code example it's taking the body as a base page and thus it works. In any case I'm going for the second example which is more correct.